# Set a daily random generated number as a state variable in React JS

Tags: reactjs, variables, state

I'm trying to create a "Bird of the day" widget that looks at a JSON list of 10,000+ birds and chooses one at random on a daily basis. I figured the easiest approach would be setting a randomly generated number to a state variable once a day and choosing the random number index of the list of birds, but I'm not finding anything in my searches that would help me achieve this with React JS.

I was going to go down the long running program route with Python, but I was hoping that I could find an alternative way in my React JS project.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need a long running program. You just need to check, on every request, whether a day has passed since the last time you checked. And you need to store when the last time you checked was. I don't know Python, but in other languages it's rather simple. You could do something similar in ReactJS, but it would have to be per-user.

Comment: You could just use local storage for this store a date and a value, check the date to see if a new value needed to be generated and stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value of the current date into localStorage:

```
const stored = storage.getItem("Date");
if (!stored) { // If no date stored, store current date
  storage.setItem("Date", new Date());
  // set state here
} else {
  const storedDate = new Date(storage.getItem("Datea"));
  const diff = (storedDate - curr) / (1000 * 3600 * 24); // difference in days
  if (diff >= 1) { // if more than one day difference
    // set state here
  }
}
```